# htaccess rule to not redirect to the folder

Tags: .htaccess

Having an issue here while trying to remove .html extension from the url. I have work.html file and work folder on the same level. I'm tying to do rewrite in htaccess file, so it would work this way:

if someone hits URL .com/work -> it would load work.html page from the root directory.
if someone hits URL .com/work/blabla -> it would load blabla.html page from work directory (.com/work/blabla.html)

But at the minute, when someone hits .com/work browser redirects to .com/work/ (work folder) and shows forbidden message. All other pages works as expected, the only issue is with the file and folder having the same name.

My rules are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Could anyone help me with this?

ADDITION:
On the picture below is file structure

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGhAc.png)

after adding rewrites all works:

```
mywebsite.com -> show index.html
mywebsite.com/contact -> show contact.html
mywebsite.com/work/avrica - > show /work/avrica.html
```

the issue I have:

```
mywebsite.com/work -> which supposed to show work.html, but in reality it shows work folder with message forbidden
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use this single rule in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: thanks Anubhava. It seems to be working better that any other solutions I have tried.
so whenever I do mysite.com/work it seems to do redirect to mysite.com/work/ but at the same time showing work.html page from the root dir. Is it possible somehow to keep url without last "/"?